# Is there a way to print a pyspark command as a SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I am reading from a Delta Table and performing some column selection and filtering using pyspark.

```
columns == ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = spark.read.load(PATH).select(*columns).where(f.col('a').like('%test%'))
```

What I would like to obtain is a SQL query representing the above operation, like:

```
select {*columns}
from PATH
where a like '%test%'
```

Is there any spark function able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is translate dataframe operations into valid SQL. This is not possible via the dataframe APIs. It can be achieved with a user-defined function though but it's very complex.

You can use the below logic as a starting point. It might not work for all use cases but should work for the one in the question above.

```
def dataframe_to_sql(df):
    # Access the logical plan
    plan = df._jdf.queryExecution().logical()
    plan_string = plan.toString()

    # Initialize SQL query
    sql_query = "SELECT "

    # Interpret select (project) expressions
    if "Project" in plan_string:
        start_idx = plan_string.find("[", plan_string.find("Project")) + 1
        end_idx = plan_string.find("]", start_idx)
        select_exprs = plan_string[start_idx:end_idx]
        sql_query += select_exprs

    # Add FROM (this requires the DataFrame to be created from a table or view)
    sql_query += f" FROM {PATH}"

    # Interpret filter (where) expressions
    if "Filter" in plan_string:
        # Adjust the starting point of filter expression extraction
        filter_start = plan_string.find("Filter") + len("Filter")
        where_clause_start = plan_string.find("(", filter_start) + 1
        where_clause_end = plan_string.find(")", where_clause_start)

        filter_expr = plan_string[where_clause_start:where_clause_end].strip()
        
        # Additional cleaning if needed, for instance, to remove attribute references
        # This part might need customization based on specific patterns in your logical plan
        filter_expr = filter_expr.replace(":", "").replace("'Filter '","")

        end_of_expression = filter_expr.find("\n")
        if end_of_expression != -1:
            filter_expr = filter_expr[:end_of_expression].strip()

        sql_query += " WHERE " + filter_expr

    return sql_query



columns == ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = spark.read.load(PATH).select(*columns).where(f.col('a').like('%test%'))

sql_query = dataframe_to_sql(data)
print(sql_query)
```